# ddclient with google domains dynamic DNS to ssh into my desktop

Tags: dns, dynamic-ip, ddclient

So I want to be able to SSH into my home desktop. I set up port forwarding on my router, and was able to ssh into my machine

```
ssh alex@2601:647:4802:b000:e938:d8b5:6111:e0fb
```

When I restart the machine, the IP address changes, so I'd like to set up Dynamic DNS. I have a domain name on google domains, which offers Dynamic DNS for free. [This tutorial](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en) is supposed to help you set it up.

I follow the steps, install ddclient, and totally overwrite ddclient.conf with what the article recommends:

```
protocol=dyndns2

use=web

server=domains.google.com

ssl=yes

login=generated_username

password=generated_password

your_resource.your_domain.tld
```

I test ddclient with the command

```
sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet
```

and I get

```
SUCCESS:  subdomain.mydomain.org: skipped: IP address was already set to 50.184.58.242.
```

which is curiously an ipv4 address, whereas I thought I had an ipv6 address. Anyhow. I've waited a little while and it doesn't work. I get

```
ssh: connect to host subdomain.mydomain.org port 22: Connection refused
```

or it hangs. Not sure where to go from here. I don't have a particularly strong mental model of how any of this works, I just want to be able to

```
ssh alex@subdomain.mydomain.org
```

whenever I please, and allow for the computer to be turned off every once in a while (meaning ip address changes).

Comment: How did you get the IPV6 address of your machine?  And are you saying the IPV6 address changes when you restart your machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out you need quotes around your password, i.e.

```
password='generated_password'
```

which the google article doesn't allude to.

Comment: Where is that documented?